# "datatype mismatch" when doing an INSERT CASE in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables, one is populated with data

```
CREATE TABLE `tableX` (`column1`    REAL);

INSERT INTO tableX VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO tableX VALUES (-3);

CREATE TABLE `tableY` 
(`rowid` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, `column2` REAL);
```

The INSERT CASE statement is

```
INSERT INTO tableY SELECT column1, 
CASE WHEN column1 >=0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END as column2 FROM tableX;
```

Error is "datatype mismatch" in my DB Browser but it seems to work in sqlfiddle...not error at least

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks :D!

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT sqlite_version();` in both tools?

Comment: DB Browser on my computer is 3.11.0

sqlfiddle is 3.8.5

Comment: Works for me in 3.16.0. Can you update that DB Browser tool, whatever it is?

Comment: Maybe needs to be a new question, but I uninstalled the old version and installed the newest. Still the .db file is saying that it is the older version! Any ideas??

Comment: It's the version of the SQLite library that the application is using; it has nothing to do with the DB file.

Comment: So I updated the .dll with the newest version. version 3.15.1. When I check the version with the command prompt it shows that it properly updated. However when I check the version in DB Browser it is still showing the old version and the code is generating the same error.  arggg :D

Thanks a ton for the help btw :)

Comment: The SQLite library is typically compiled directly into the application; almost nobody uses the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but it is a work around.

```
CREATE TABLE `tableX` (`column1`    REAL);
INSERT INTO tableX VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO tableX VALUES (-3);

CREATE TABLE `tableZ` (`column1` REAL, `column3` REAL);
INSERT INTO tableZ SELECT column1, 
CASE WHEN column1 >=0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END as column3 FROM tableX;

CREATE TABLE 'tableY' (`rowid` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, `column2` REAL)
INSERT INTO tableY (column2) SELECT column3 FROM tableZ;

DROP TABLE tableZ;
```